# parsing Argument of a .txt file by fgets in C

Tags: c, parsing, file-io

i have `Members.txt`file which i am reading below items:

```
3
Rebaz salimi 3840221821 09188888888
4
95120486525
```

below codes gave me this run time error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type|
```

C language codes:

```
FILE *fp,*ft,*fs;

struct MEMBERS
{
    int code;
    char Fname[40];
    char Lname[40];
    int Pnum[20];
    float bedeh;
    float credit;
    int count[1];
    struct meroDate issued;
    struct meroDate duedate;
};

struct MEMBERS b;

int main()
{
    int i = 0, line = 5;
    char w[100];
    int str[100];
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("Members.txt","r");
    if (myfile== NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(line--){
        fgets(str,2,myfile);
        if(sscanf(str, "%d", &b.count[0])==1)){
            printf("%d\n", b.count[0]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(myfile);

    return 0;

}
```

any idea what is the problem?

Comment: `int str[100];` --> `char str[100];` Because The first argument of `fgets` requires a `char *`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it works! but i m wondering why the integers in .txt file can't be read in INT first?! and supposly should be read as CHAR first!

Comment: You can use `sscanf` to read the contents as `int`. `fgets` just reads as a c-string. Read [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Also `fgets(str,2,myfile);` --> `fgets(str, 100, myfile);` or `fgets(str, sizeof str, myfile);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY cool tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to the declartion or man page for C functions when use.
fgets() requires array of chars for 1st argument,
and size of the 1st argmuent for 2nd argument.

```
int str[100];
fgets(str, 2, myfile);
```

should be,

```
char str[100];
fgets(str, sizeof(str), myfile);
```

Converting array of chars into int or double requires another funtion calls like atoi() or atof().

Comment: havent attention to this! tnx!